# Unity UI Image Prevent Camera To Render All Object In Front Of It

Tags: unity, 2d

i confused why is this happen , i know there's already available post that discuss this but i cannot find it at google. My problem is that my UI image with sprite hide rendering all object in front of it ( so the camera view only show the image ) .

Screenshot In 3D Mode :

I Put A Square Object Right In Front Of The Image

[image: in front of image]

And This Is The Camera Position With Camera Preview

[image: camera postion EASTER EGG !]

Sorry i only can put 2 screenshot because below reputation 10 i can't put more than 2 picture .

As you see , the camera should render the " StartBox " either " MenuBox " but none are rendered even it's in front of camera view

Answer (score 1):

Your Canvas is set to *Screen Space Overlay* which means it renders on top of everything in the scene. If you want to have a stretched background image behind objects in the scene you will need to use either a *World Space* Canvas or *Screen Space Camera*. Tutorial on the canvas system here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-canvas

Comment: In this case, the 'Screen Space Camera' mode would be the ideal, instead of 'World Space'. Just ensure that the plane distance is set far enough back.

Comment: true. good point.